# Error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: { using .NET core 3

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, postman

I don't understand why get an error "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {"?

My startup config:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opts => {
            opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    );
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost("{accountId}/top-up")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TopUp([FromBody] decimal amount, [FromRoute] int accountId)
{
    //...
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters do not match the data you passed in

```
// param [FromBody] decimal amount
```

Matchs

```
100
```

---

```
public class Foo {
 public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
//param [FromBody]Foo model
```

Matchs

```
{
 "amount":100
}
```